# Парсинг JSON объектов

Tags: javascript, json

Всем привет! Возникла некоторая трудность с парсингом JSON объектов следующего типа:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "type": "json",
        "code": 200,
        "message": "сообщение",
        "output": {
            "services": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "serviceType": "тип сервиса",
                    "serviceParams": {
                        "plan": {
                            "name": "название",
                            "poster": "постер"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "month": 90,
                            "year": 1080
                        },
                        "currency": "rub",
                        "more": {
                            ненужные пустяки
                        }
                    },
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Есть код, отправляющий и обрабатывающий запрос:

```
fetch('api/getServices?type=тип').then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    response.json().then((result) => {
                        if(result.status != 'success') {
                          alert(`Произошла ошибка: ${result.data.message} / код: ${result.data.code}`);
                        }  else {
                          console.log(`[сайт] ${result.data.message}`);
                           Object.values(result.data.output.services).forEach(res => 
                               alert(res.plan.name)
                              )
                        }
                      })
                } else throw new Error(`response status code ${response.status}`)
            }).catch(err => console.log(`[сайт] Fetch Error: ${err}`))
```

На выходе получаю ошибку **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')**
Если же использовать,  например,

```
alert(res.active)
```

- все будет отображаться **корректно**

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как реализовать задуманное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert(res.serviceParams.plan.name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Да, серьезно. Очень странно, что пропустил такой элементарнейший пустяк. Спасибо!

Comment: @JohnChees Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Знаю, нельзя пока пометить вопрос, как решённый. Через 4 минуты отмечу, спасибо ;)